# I want to add my own style pop-up dialogue box in my android app as shown in image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

As shown in image the above part is my layout and i want to add pop-up like part below in image.So how can i create it and how can i handle dialogue box button event.??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class PopupforeditActivity extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alphabetslist);

    callalertDialogueCustom();


} 

   public void callalertDialogueCustom(){

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(PopupforeditActivity.this);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup); // This is my Custom Layout
    dialog.setTitle("This is my custom dialog box");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    //there are a lot of settings, for dialog, check them all out!

    //set up text
    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    text.setText("Lots of Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii");

    EditText edt=(EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtxtName);
    edt.setText("i am binded this time");

    //set up image view
   /* ImageView img = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.nista_logo);*/

    //set up button
    Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on Save",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    Button button1 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         //finish();
        dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    //now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it    
    dialog.show();


}

}
```

My Custom Layout GUI

[image]

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rltvview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_black_transparent">

    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scrlview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_orange_matte"/>


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtxtName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:hint="hii"
            android:lines="5"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSave" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:text="Save"
                android:layout_margin="10dip"/>
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:layout_margin="10dip"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Just Call this **callalertDialogueCustom();** method from any place according to your need.. It will create Custom Dialogue also and will handle the click events also for it

Comment: final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(PopupforeditActivity.this);  Whats "POPupforeditActivity" used for?

Comment: "PopupforeditActivity.this" its the name of the activity on which I am adding it. you can try its alternative "this"

final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

Comment: it is used for giving the instance of the activity to the Dialogue to which we will bind it... that means the activity which will act as its parent

Answer (score 4):

```
public class Add extends Activity{

PopupWindow popUp;
Dialog myDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.add);

    myDialog = new Dialog(Add.this);
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup50);
    myDialog.setTitle("Please Pay Attention!");
    myDialog.setCancelable(true);

    //for save
  Button popone = (Button)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
  popone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
  {
  public void onClick(View v) 
  {

      myDialog.dismiss();

     }
  });


  //for cancel
  Button poptwo = (Button)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.button2);
  poptwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
  {
  public void onClick(View v) 
  {


    Intent CheckProfile = new Intent(Add.this, UserActivity.class);
    startActivity(CheckProfile);
    myDialog.dismiss();


     }
  });


  myDialog.show();


}
```

and this is XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:background="#00FFFF"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/popUp_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="@string/pop50"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/popUp_text"
    android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:text="Cancel" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginRight="69dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
    android:text="  Ok  " />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: here if i click on CANCEL then the what happen??

Comment: it redirects to de same page.. or u can redirect to another activity.. its your choice

Answer (score 2):

I have something similar to show an about screen that might be helpful for you:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v) {
        show_about();              
    }
});

...

private void showAbout() {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog (context);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.about);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    dialog.show();      
}
```

The xml bit:

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:text="An app for the Newcastle Cloud Team"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/coche3" />

    ...

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: yeah thanks this will help too.But i want an edittext and OK button in my dialogue box

Comment: Just add it to the XML. That's the easy bit! :-)

Comment: ohk but is there any special event for Dialogue button or it is same as normal button???

Comment: Same I think... just give it a try and let us know.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFF" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"/>/>

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
     android:layout_width="100px"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/image"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
     android:text=" Ok " />
```

put this code inside a buton event or what ever u want

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.coustom);
            dialog.setTitle("Title...");

            // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText("Android custom dialog ");
            ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
```

Comment: instead of textview i want edittext. so can i use edittext in this??

Comment: yes you can but that is not advised you can get the edit text in the same way as the btn is obtained

Comment: i dont understand but what i want is i want to insert a password in edittext so that i can compare it from my database.

Comment: EditText et= (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ureditextid);
et.getText().ToString();